# Protect a Range of Cells in Excel 2007 using a digital signature

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a worksheet where I need to lock two specific ranges of cells with two different digital signatures. Essentially, one person will enter data and sign and then the file will be sent to another for more data entry that will also need to be signed. So far, I haven't been able to use the digital signature except to convert the entire workbook to Read-Only.

Answer (score 1):

You can only [currently](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-digital-signature-to-a-file-or-macro-project-HP005249557.aspx) use a digital signature on an entire workbook or a macro project, not a range

Comment: Dead link - please update

Comment: @JonnyWright Thanks, I'll try to find something when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks, sorry I just read how blunt my comment was! Only reason I commented is your comment suggests that it may be possible at some point. Just keen to know of it is

Comment: @JonnyWright no worries, I changed the tag on the question to Excel 2007 - blunt or not it's never fun to have out of date info!